# Test time series performance across subjects against chance

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, svm

I'm wondering if anyone had any advice on testing where (if at all) the average of several time series deviates against chance. That is, I have an output from an SVM, computed at several time points, and I want to determine the times at which the SVM performs better than 50% chance across six subjects. Therefore, I have 6 time series that are the performance output of the SVM and I want to determine the times at which (on average) these differ significantly from chance.

I was initially thinking of doing something like a cluster-based permutation test, where I created a distribution with a mean of 50 and tested my time series against this, shuffling the data each time and then looking at significance at the cluster level, but I can't see anyone doing this, so I'm not sure that this would be correct. Any help and input is always very much appreciated! Maybe I'm overlooking a simple solution, but my brain can't find it right now.